# modifying linked list node data

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

**How to modify node data?**
I am trying to modify the data content of head node or any other node but wont able to do it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};
void traverseList(struct Node *ptr)
{
    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        printf("element is:%d\n", ptr->data);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}
int main()
{
    struct Node *head;
    struct Node *second;
    struct Node *third;
    head = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    second = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    third = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    head->data = 7;
    head->next = second;
    second->data = 122;
    second->next = third;
    third->data = 34;
    third->next = NULL;

    traverseList(head);
    
    free(head);
    free(second);
    free(third);
    return 0;
}
```

I need to know how to modify the node data of head node

Comment: What is the problem you're having ?

Comment: @rpg `head->next = second;` is fine. It makes the head node "point" to the second node

Comment: Further [Singly Linked List of Integers (add, del, print)](https://pastebin.com/B4WFfHfF) may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a function that changes data in the node at index (aka position) N in the list. If the first element is at index zero, it could look like:

```
int update_at(struct Node *ptr, unsigned idx, int data)
{
    while (ptr != NULL && idx > 0)
    {
        ptr = ptr->next;
        --idx;
    }
    if (ptr == NULL) return -1; // Node not found
    ptr->data = data;
    return 0;
}
```

and call it like

```
if (update_at(head, 1, 42))  // Update node at index 1
{
    // Update failed - add some error handling
    ...
}
```

Comment: Or `while (ptr && idx--) ptr = ptr->next;` ... for the unreadable crowd `:)`

Comment: True. More compact but I decided to "spell it out". Anyway, I doubt there will much (if any) difference in the executable.